# I want to update 'points' field value in Customer table but it is throwing error as Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'points' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

Here is my customer model

```
protected $table = 'customers';

    protected $fillable = [
    
      'name', 'email','customer_number', 'password','customer_ph_number' //added by me
    ];


    protected $appends = [
      'account_active', 'avatar', 'points','campaign_text', 'number', 'events'
    ];

    protected $hidden =
     [
      'id', 'campaign_id', 'history', 'campaign', 'events', 'password', 'remember_token', 'account', 'global_points', 'account_id', 'remote_customer_id', 'previous_remote_customer_id', 'domain', 'company', 'company_slug', 'files_dir', 'verification_code', 'token', 'login_code', 'login_code_valid_until', 'signup_ip_address', 'logins', 'last_login', 'last_login_ip_address', 'expires', 'customer_number', 'lead_source', 'lead_source_module', 'lead_status', 'lead_type', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'created_at', 'salutation', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'job_title', 'date_of_birth', 'phone', 'mobile', 'website', 'fax', 'street1', 'street2', 'city', 'state', 'postal_code', 'country_code', 'zoom', 'lat', 'lng', 'primary_account', 'email_verified_at', 'hourly_rate', 'notes', 'additional_fields', 'settings', 'tags', 'attributes', 'meta', 'minus_sign', 'account_active', 'bank', 'bank_id', 'currency_code', 'ecode_swift', 'first_day_of_week', 'iban', 'id_number', 'id', 'media', 'shipping_city', 'shipping_country_code', 'shipping_lat', 'shipping_lng', 'shipping_postal_code', 'shipping_state', 'shipping_street1', 'shipping_street2', 'shipping_zoom', 'vat_number', 'gender', 'mobile_business', 'mobile_personal', 'phone_business', 'phone_personal', 'social'
    ];


    protected $casts = [
      'uuid' => 'uuid',
      'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
      'social' => 'json',
      'settings' => 'json',
      'tags' => 'json',
      'attributes' => 'json',
      'meta' => 'json'
    ];
    public static function getCreateForm() {
      $owner = [
        'tab1' => [
          'text' => __('General'),
          'subs' => [
            'sub1' => [
              'items' => [
                ['type' => 'text', 'column' => 'name', 'text' => __('Name '), 'validate' => 'required|max:32', 'required' => true],
                ['type' => 'email', 'column' => 'email', 'text' => __('E-mail address'), 'validate' => 'required|email|max:64', 'required' => true],
                ['type' => 'password', 'column' => 'password', 'text' => __('Password'), 'hint_edit' => __('Leave blank to keep current password'), 'validate' => 'nullable|min:8|max:32', 'validate_create' => 'required|min:8|max:32', 'required_create' => true],
                // ['type' => 'text', 'column' => 'customer_number', 'text' => __('Phone Number'), 'hint_edit' => __('Please enter Your phone number here'), 'validate' => 'required|min:10|max:10', 'required'=>true],
                ['type' => 'text', 'column' => 'customer_ph_number', 'text' => __('Phone Number'), 'hint_edit' => __('Please enter Your phone number here'), 'validate' => 'required|min:10|max:10', 'required'=>true],
                ['type' => 'image', 'image' => ['thumb_width' => '140px', 'thumb_height' => '140px'], 'column' => 'avatar', 'text' => __('Avatar'), 'validate' => 'nullable', 'icon' => 'account_circle', 'class' => 'img-rounded my-3'],
                ['type' => 'boolean', 'default' => true, 'column' => 'active', 'text' => __('Active'), 'validate' => 'nullable']
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ];
      $reseller = $owner;
      $user = $owner;

      return [
        1 => $owner,
        2 => $reseller,
        3 => $user
      ];
    }
```

Here is 'customer' table schema

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
      
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('account_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
        $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->bigInteger('campaign_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
        $table->foreign('campaign_id')->references('id')->on('campaigns')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->tinyInteger('role')->unsigned()->default(1);
        $table->boolean('active')->default(true);
        $table->string('remote_customer_id', 200)->nullable();
        $table->string('previous_remote_customer_id', 200)->nullable();
        $table->string('customer_number', 32)->nullable();
        $table->string('name', 64)->nullable();
        $table->string('email', 128)->nullable();
        $table->string('verification_code', 64)->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->string('token')->nullable();
        $table->string('login_code', 64)->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('login_code_valid_until')->nullable();
        $table->string('language', 5)->nullable();
        $table->string('locale', 24)->nullable();
        $table->char('currency_code', 3)->nullable();
        $table->string('timezone', 32)->nullable();
        $table->tinyInteger('first_day_of_week')->nullable();

        $table->ipAddress('signup_ip_address')->nullable();
        $table->integer('logins')->default(0)->unsigned();
        $table->dateTime('last_login')->nullable();
        $table->ipAddress('last_login_ip_address')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('expires')->nullable();

        $table->string('salutation', 32)->nullable();
        $table->string('first_name', 64)->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name', 64)->nullable();
        $table->tinyInteger('gender')->nullable();
        $table->string('job_title', 64)->nullable();
        $table->date('date_of_birth')->nullable();
        $table->string('lead_source', 250)->nullable();
        $table->string('lead_source_module', 128)->nullable();
        $table->string('lead_status', 128)->nullable();
        $table->string('lead_type', 128)->nullable();
        $table->string('phone', 32)->nullable();
        $table->string('mobile', 32)->nullable();
        $table->string('website', 250)->nullable();
        $table->string('fax', 32)->nullable();
        $table->string('street1', 250)->nullable();
        $table->string('street2', 250)->nullable();
        $table->string('city', 64)->nullable();
        $table->string('state', 64)->nullable();
        $table->string('postal_code', 32)->nullable();
        $table->char('country_code', 2)->nullable();

        // Location
        $table->tinyInteger('zoom')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('lat', 17, 14)->nullable();
        $table->decimal('lng', 18, 15)->nullable();

        $table->string('company', 96)->nullable();
        $table->string('shipping_street1', 250)->nullable();
        $table->string('shipping_street2', 250)->nullable();
        $table->string('shipping_city', 64)->nullable();
        $table->string('shipping_state', 64)->nullable();
        $table->string('shipping_postal_code', 32)->nullable();
        $table->char('shipping_country_code', 2)->nullable();

        // Shipping location
        $table->tinyInteger('shipping_zoom')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('shipping_lat', 17, 14)->nullable();
        $table->decimal('shipping_lng', 18, 15)->nullable();

        $table->string('vat_number', 250)->nullable();
        $table->string('id_number', 250)->nullable();
        $table->string('bank', 250)->nullable();
        $table->string('bank_id', 250)->nullable();
        $table->string('ecode_swift', 250)->nullable();
        $table->string('iban', 250)->nullable();
        $table->mediumText('notes')->nullable();

        $table->json('settings')->nullable();
        $table->json('tags')->nullable();
        $table->json('attributes')->nullable();
        $table->json('meta')->nullable();

        $table->bigInteger('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
        $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->bigInteger('updated_by')->nullable()->unsigned();

        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `customers` ADD `uuid` BINARY(16) UNIQUE NULL AFTER `id`;');
}
```

Here is what i did to update the column

```
public function newTransaction(Request $request){
$account = app()->make('account');
$user = Customer::withoutGlobalScopes()->where('id', Auth::user('customer')->id)->where('campaign_id', $campaign->id)->firstOrFail();
$locale = request('locale', config('system.default_language'));
app()->setLocale($locale);

$previousSikka = $user->points; //For getting previous all sikka
$sending_amount = $request->sending_amount;
$remarks =$request->transaction_remarks; 
$latest_sikka = (int)($sending_amount / 100);
$total_sikka = $latest_sikka + $previousSikka ;
$NPRvalue = $total_sikka / 100;
Customer::where('id', Auth::user('customer')->id)->update(array('points' => $total_sikka));
return response()->json([
  'status'=>'success',
  "totalSikka"=>($total_sikka),
  "pointsss"=>$customers_point,
  "total_sikka"=>$total_sikka

],200);
```

}

```
But it is throwing error as local.ERROR: 

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'points' in
> 'field list' (SQL: update `customers` set `points` = 400,
> `customers`.`updated_at` = 2023-01-11 06:05:40 where `id` = 40)
> {"userId":40,"exception":"[object]
> (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]:
> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'points' in 'field list' (SQL:
> update `customers` set `points` = 400, `customers`.`updated_at` =
> 2023-01-11 06:05:40 where `id` = 40) at
> C:\\laragon\\www\\earnsikka\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:669)
> [stacktrace]

I want the points to be updated in customer table
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your issue is with your update statement:**

```
Customer::where('id', Auth::user('customer')->id)->update(array('points' => $total_sikka));
```

You are trying to update the customers table and it doesn't have the `points` column. Also, I don't see the column `points` in your migration so it seems like its not there.

But I saw that you have points in the user! and I think you are trying to update the user rather than the customer.

**In that case you simply need to update your user:**

```
//Customer::where('id', Auth::user('customer')->id)->update(array('points' => $total_sikka));

//Add this instead to update the user directly;
$user->update(['points' => $total_sikka]);
```

Because I saw that you are also getting the points using the user:

```
$previousSikka = $user->points; //For getting previous all sikka
```